# Programming question(death battle) on probability

Tags: probability

In a crossover fantasy universe, houin kyoma is up in a battle against powerful monster nomu that can kill him in a single blow. However being a brilliant scientist kyoma found a way to pause time for exactly M seconds. Each second, kyoma attacks nomu with certain power, which will reduce his health points by that exact power Initially nomu had H health points. Nomu dies when his health points reach 0, Normally kyoma performs normal attack with power A. Besides from kyomas brilliance, luck plays a major role in events of this universe. Kyoma luck L is defined as probability of performing a super attack. A super attack increases power of normal attack by C. Given this information calculate and print the probability that kyoma kills nomu and survives. If kyoma dies print RIP.

Input format 
First line is integer T denoting number test cases. Each test case consist of single line with space separated number A H L1 L2 M C. Where luck L is defined as L1/L2. Other number are, as described above

Output 
Print probability that kyoma kills nomu in form p1/p2 where p1<=p2 and gcd(p1,p2)=1. If impossible, print RIP without quotes

Example
input
1 10 33 7 10 3 2 Output 98/125

How the probability comes to 98/125?

I tried to get answer by taking
The possibilities in which the monster get killed upon the total possibilities

Like 
(10 10 10)
(10 10 12) 
(10 12 12)
(12 12 12)
And so on 
An attack every second

But it's not working

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are dealing with here is called binomial distribution. See [Binomial Distribution](https://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/binomial.aspx)

First, we find monster health points that will remain after $M$ standard attacks. It's $33-3\cdot 10=3$. Clearly Kyoma needs at least 2 successful super attacks to win.

The probability of a successful supper attack is $7 \over 10$. So the probability of two successful super attacks happening is $\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{10}$. However this can happen in three ways (super attack did not happen on the first, second or third second) so we multiply this by $3$.

The probability of three successful super attacks happening is $\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10}$. There is only one way this can happen.

FInally, adding two probabilities together we have $$\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{9}{10}+\frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10} \cdot \frac{7}{10}=\frac{98}{125}$$